# .ClientTemplate issue when calling a $.get() Telerik MVC3 Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, telerik-grid

So, what the end intent really is, is to have a normalized Grid. Meaning I want to store an ID, but display the value in the Master Grid (as a text field, not a combo box).

So I tried to go about it with a .ClientTemplate. My Grid is AJAX bound, leaving me with the client template:

```
columns.Bound(fs => fs.ID2).ClientTemplate("<#= fixId(ID2) #>")
```

And a Javascript call:

```
function fixId(e) {
    var idValue= "ears";
    $.get("/controller/_Action", { Id: e }, function (data) {
        idValue= data;
    });
    return idValue;
}
```

But the value is never set to the data return result (which is JSON) and I verified it's the correct data because I can do an alert(data) and it's what I want.

I'm guessing it's because it's a double AJAX call but I don't know any way around this.

I've tried to put it on clientEvents like onDataBound, or onRowDataBound. Which work if the grid has data, but throws a Javascript error when adding new data. As well as slowing down the load time on the grid.

Any help would be great! thanks :)

Comment: looks like changing the Javascript to:
var output = "";
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            async: false,
            url: "/conrtoller/_Action",
            data: { ID: e }
        }).done(function (out) {
            output = out;
        });
        return output;

fixed it